# Printing the last char in a file

Tags: c

I have created a 4B file with contents `asdf`. However, when I do the following:

```
fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_END);
printf("%c", fgetc(fptr));
```

The last character printed is `?`.

I need to to do:

```
fseek(fptr, -1, SEEK_END);
printf("%c", fgetc(fptr));
```

for it to print the letter `f`. Why is this so? What is considered "the end" of a file in `fseek` ?

Comment: Maybe because of line or file ending character. `EOF`, `\r\n`, `\n`

Comment: Use this `char c = fgetc(fp); printf("%d", c);` if it print -1 `fgetc()` have error.

Comment: I think you need a version of tail in C or use another method to read each character until `EOF` then store correct character  (actual last one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code snippet to see weird behavior reason.

***Code***

```
int c = fgetc(fp);
if (c == EOF && ferror(fp))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "ddd");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}else if(c == EOF){
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "EOF");
}
```

I think you reach to end of file and `EOF` will be print.
as `EOF` as a predefined constant equals to -1 you can see -1 by printing `fgetc()` output value.

man page of `fgetc()` says:

> RETURN VALUE
> fgetc(),  getc(), and getchar() return the character read as an unsigned char cast to an int or EOF on
> end of file or error.

Answer (score 0):

The offsets that `fseek` uses are 0-based.  (Just like arrays in C.)  So the offsets in your 4-byte file are like this:

```
 a  s  d  f
 0  1  2  3
```

And then, if you use `SEEK_END`, it subtracts from the *total* size of the file.  So `fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_END)` is the same as `fseek(fptr, 4-0, SEEK_SET)`.  In other words, these are the results you get with negative offsets and `SEEK_END`:

```
 a  s  d  f
-4 -3 -2 -1
```

So your problem is that when you use an offset of `0` with `SEEK_END`, you're seeking to the *very* end of the file.  When you try to read a character there, `fgetc` returns `EOF`.  But you're not checking for that.  When you try to print the `EOF` marker as a character, you're getting a `?` instead.  (Remember, `EOF` is not an actual character.  It's a marker indicating that no character could be read.)

Calling `fseek(fptr, -1, SEEK_END)` is the correct way to seek to the last character that's actually in the file.  That's the same as `fseek(fptr, 4-1, SEEK_SET)`, or `fseek(fptr, 3, SEEK_SET)`.

In general, it' a good idea to always check for EOF.  So I would write

```
fseek(fptr, -1, SEEK_END);
int c = fgetc(fptr);
if(c == EOF)
     printf("EOF\n");
else printf("%c\n", c);
```